# Problems running Storybook build with Angular

Tags: angular, storybook

I had a question about building Storybook without running it.
I try to launch it with the following command in package.json file scripts section :  `"build-storybook": "npm run docs:json && build-storybook"` by running `npm run build-storybook`. But when the console try to execute the `build-storybook` part of the command It display the following error :

> Invalid command: build-storybook.
> See --help for a list of available commands.

Is there a particular thing to do before executing this command?

I run storybook 6 with Angular.

Comment: Can you specify what do you mean by "get to  'build-storybook'"? Do you mean you run 'npm run build-storybook'? The message you pasted sounds more like some shell message and not npm message.

Comment: Question edited. Yes I run ```npm run build-storybook```

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to overcome this issue by cleaning up a bit with `rm -rf node_modules` and then running `npm install`.